# How to select Polymer paper-button .button-content?

Tags: polymer

I want to squash the paper-button, however it's declared as

```
  /* line 110 */
  .button-content {
    padding: 0.7em 0.57em
  }
```

I want to set the style to `padding:0;`

How do I select .button-content?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
paper-button /deep/ .button-content{
     padding: 0.7em 0.57em
}
```

Comment: I feel like I tried that several times without it working. But awesome it works today :P

Comment: Might be a CSS specificity issue if it doesnt work, chrome devtools is useful to spot those. And maybe consider using `paper-button::shadow .button-content ` instead of the broader `/deep/` version

Comment: paper-button::shadow .button-content worked as a selector, but I was looking to change the content property (so I could use classes to modify a toggle). the content property doesn't respond in case anyone else is trying this.

Answer (score 2):

/deep/ and ::shadow are being [deprecated](https://blog.polymer-project.org/announcements/2015/12/01/deprecating-deep/).

paper-button padding can be set to zero using mixins:

```
<style>
    :host {
        --paper-button: {
            padding: 0;
        }
    }
</style>
```

For more information, see: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling.html#custom-css-mixins